# Change the "Create [content type]" title

Tags: nodes, string-overrides

I allow registered users to create content of type X, so they can go to the /node/add/X page and fill in the form. However, I want to give this page a bespoke title, i.e. "Make an X" rather than "Create X". I have tried adding a string override in settings.php, and also tried with the [string overrides module](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides). However, neither of these worked.

What is the best way to do this? (I don't want to install another module if I can avoid it, I already have too many and this seems like a trivial issue).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
function MY_MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == 'myContentType_node_form') {
         drupal_set_title('Your custom title');     
     }
 }
```

Comment: So create a module just for this functionality? That seems a bit like overkill doesn't it?

Comment: @James this could also be included in the template.php file of the theme, just replace MY_MODULE_NAME with the theme name